# Why RouterLink adds the input to the end of current URL in bracket

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

Lets say my url is: http://localhost:4200/user_id/home. Here is my button code:

```
  <ion-button [routerLink]="['some_user_id', 'payments']" routerLinkActive="selected">
    <ion-label class="label">Payments</ion-label>
  </ion-button>
```

Because I was getting `Error: Cannot match any routes.` I started to investigate the problem and I come to, that routerLink is generating such DOM element:

```
<a href="user_id/home/(some_user_id/payments)" class="button-native" part="native">
```

When (in the same component) I use router to navigate, like:

```
this.router.navigate('some_user_id', 'payments'])
```

all works.

What is the problem that generated href isn't just `<a href="some_user_id/payments" class="button-native" part="native"> as allways`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `routerLink` is a directive and it does a few other things behind the scenes.

Let's see [what happens](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L203-L223) when you click on an element which has the `RouterLink` directive:

```js
@Directive({selector: ':not(a):not(area)[routerLink]'})
export class RouterLink {
  /* ... */

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick(): boolean {
    const extras = {
      skipLocationChange: attrBoolValue(this.skipLocationChange),
      replaceUrl: attrBoolValue(this.replaceUrl),
      state: this.state,
    };
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlTree, extras);
    return true;
  }

  get urlTree(): UrlTree {
    return this.router.createUrlTree(this.commands, {
      relativeTo: this.route, // !
      queryParams: this.queryParams,
      fragment: this.fragment,
      preserveQueryParams: attrBoolValue(this.preserve),
      queryParamsHandling: this.queryParamsHandling,
      preserveFragment: attrBoolValue(this.preserveFragment),
    });
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

Keep an eye on `relativeTo: this.route`, where `this.route` points to the current `ActivatedRoute`(e.g the one associated with `/home`).

What [`Router.createUrlTree`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L970) does is to apply a set of `commands` to the current URL tree, which will result in a new URL tree. In your case, the `commands` are `['some_user_id', 'payments']`.

```js
createUrlTree(commands: any[], navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {}): UrlTree {
  const {
    relativeTo,
    queryParams,
    fragment,
    preserveQueryParams,
    queryParamsHandling,
    preserveFragment
  } = navigationExtras;
  
  /* .... */

  const a = relativeTo || this.routerState.root;
  const f = preserveFragment ? this.currentUrlTree.fragment : fragment;
  let q: Params|null = null;
  
  /* ... resolving query params based on the `queryParamsHandling` strategy */

  return createUrlTree(a, this.currentUrlTree, commands, q!, f!);
}
```

[`createUrlTree`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/create_url_tree.ts#L14) is where the magic happens:

```js
export function createUrlTree(
    route: ActivatedRoute, urlTree: UrlTree, commands: any[], queryParams: Params,
    fragment: string): UrlTree {
  // `route` - that one which corresponds to `/home`
  // `commends` - `['some_user_id', 'payments']`
  // `urlTree` - a tree of UrlSegmentGroups, we'll have a closer look a bit later

  if (commands.length === 0) { /* Not our case */ }

  /* 
  a command might also be one of these objects: 
    * { outlets: { outletName: path } }
    * { k1: v1, k2: v2 } - segment parameters
    * { segmentPath: path }

    but in this case, it will simply be a Navigation object {
      isAbsolute: false,
      numberOfDoubleDots: 0,
      commands: ['some_user_id', 'payments']
    }
  */
  const nav = computeNavigation(commands);

  if (nav.toRoot()) { 
    /* Not our case;  */ 
    /* It would've been if: this.isAbsolute && this.commands.length === 1 && this.commands[0] == '/' */
  }

  /* 
  We'd get a new `Position` object: `return new Position(g, false, ci - dd);`
  where `dd` - number of double dots = 0 and `ci` - current index = 1
  why is it 1? - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/create_url_tree.ts#L160
  */
  const startingPosition = findStartingPosition(nav, urlTree, route);

  const segmentGroup = startingPosition.processChildren ?
      updateSegmentGroupChildren(
          startingPosition.segmentGroup, startingPosition.index, nav.commands) :
      updateSegmentGroup(startingPosition.segmentGroup, startingPosition.index, nav.commands);
  return tree(startingPosition.segmentGroup, segmentGroup, urlTree, queryParams, fragment);
}
```

`segmentGroup` would be the result of `updateSegmentGroup`. It will eventually reach [`createNewSegmentGroup`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/create_url_tree.ts#L273):

```js
function createNewSegmentGroup(
    segmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup, startIndex: number, commands: any[]): UrlSegmentGroup {
  // Everything before the `startIndex`
  const paths = segmentGroup.segments.slice(0, startIndex); 

  let i = 0;
  while (i < commands.length) {
    if (typeof commands[i] === 'object' && commands[i].outlets !== undefined) {
      /* Not our case */
    }

    // if we start with an object literal, we need to reuse the path part from the segment
    // That's why the `modifier` is 1 if there are no parameters: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/create_url_tree.ts#L160
    if (i === 0 && isMatrixParams(commands[0])) {
      const p = segmentGroup.segments[startIndex];
      paths.push(new UrlSegment(p.path, commands[0]));
      i++;
      continue;
    }

    const curr = getPath(commands[i]);
    const next = (i < commands.length - 1) ? commands[i + 1] : null;
    if (curr && next && isMatrixParams(next)) {
      paths.push(new UrlSegment(curr, stringify(next)));
      i += 2;
    } else {

      // Adding the commands(`['some_user_id', 'payments']`) the the previous segments
      // Which explains why you're getting the current behavior
      paths.push(new UrlSegment(curr, {}));
      i++;
    }
  }
  return new UrlSegmentGroup(paths, {});
}
```

*Note: this walk-through is based on this [ng-run demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/GvLjxraEibHiqxdYqihB).*

---

An URL can have this structure: `segment?queryParams#fragment`.

An `UrlSegmentGroup` can have an array of `UrlSegments` and an object of child `UrlSegmentGroup`s:

```js
export class UrlSegmentGroup {
  /* ... */

  parent: UrlSegmentGroup|null = null;

  constructor(
      public segments: UrlSegment[],
      public children: {[key: string]: UrlSegmentGroup}) {
    forEach(children, (v: any, k: any) => v.parent = this);
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

For example, we might have a more complex URL, such as `foo/123/(a//named:b)`. The resulted `UrlSegmentGroup` will be this:

```js
{
  segments: [], // The root UrlSegmentGroup never has any segments
  children: {
    primary: {
      segments: [{ path: 'foo', parameters: {} }, { path: '123', parameters: {} }],
      children: {
        primary: { segments: [{ path: 'a', parameters: {} }], children: {} },
        named: { segments: [{ path: 'b', parameters: {} }], children: {} },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

which would match a route configuration like this:

```js
{
  {
    path: 'foo/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./foo/foo.module').then(m => m.FooModule)
  },

  // foo.module.ts
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'b',
    component: BComponent,
    outlet: 'named',
  },
}
```

You can experiment with this example in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-base-url-parser?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffoo%2Ffoo.module.ts).

As you can see, `UrlSegmentGroup`'s children are delimited by `()`. The names of these children are the **router outlet**.

In `/(a//named:b)`, because it uses a `/` before `(`, `a` will be segment of the **primary outlet**. `//` is the separator for router outlets. Finally, `named:b` follows this structure: `outletName:segmentPath`.

Another thing that should be mentioned is the `UrlSegment`'s `parameters` property. Besides **positional parameters**(e.g `foo/:a/:b`), segments can have parameters declared like this: `segment/path;k1=v1;k2=v2`;

So, an `UrlTree` has 3 important properties: the `root` `UrlSegmentGroup`, the `queryParams` object and the `fragment` of the issued URL.

---

`this.router.navigate('some_user_id', 'payments'])` works because [`Router.navigate`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L1066-L1070) will eventually call `Router.createUrlTree`:

```js
navigate(commands: any[], extras: NavigationExtras = {skipLocationChange: false}):
    Promise<boolean> {
  validateCommands(commands);
  return this.navigateByUrl(this.createUrlTree(commands, extras), extras);
}
```

Then, `const a = relativeTo || this.routerState.root;` will be reached inside `Router.createUrlTree` and since there is no `relativeTo`(as opposed to `RouterLink`), it will be relative to the root `ActivatedRoute`.

You can get the same behavior with `routerLink`, by adding `/` at the beginning of the first command: `[routerLink]="['/some_user_id', 'payments']"`